# Cannot GET /landingPage

Tags: javascript, express, routes, get

I am trying to create a login page with two types of user, Admin and User.

I have created the HTML and a login page which works ok, using the code below, when I try to input incorrect details it fails as it should but when I put a valid username and password that is sitting in my DB it is giving me the message 'Cannot GET /landingPage'. The landing page HTML exists but I think it is to do with the .redirect as if I use .send it sends a message.

The expected behaviour is that when I click login with a valid username and password that is held in my db, the page will redirect away from the login page, to the landingPage.

Is anyone able to help please?

Thanks in advance!!!

```
// Database connection
const db = new sqlite3.Database('./db/database.db');

// LocalHost right now
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // Render login page
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/login.html');
});

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  // Retrieve the user from the database
  db.get('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?', username, (err, row) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    }

    if (!row) {
      return res.status(401).send('Invalid credentials');
    }

    // Check if the provided password matches the stored password
    if (row.password !== password) {
      return res.status(401).send('Invalid credentials');
    }

    return res.status(200).redirect('/landingPage');
  });
});
```

Comment: I'd been struggling for days with this and 10 mins after posting this I resolved it by doing this ...

    return res.status(200).redirect('/landingPage');


  });
});

app.get('/landingPage', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/views/landingPage.html'));
});